# Create view (lookat) matrix for opengl manually in java

Tags: java, opengl, matrix

I'm using `JOGL` and `Box2d` to write a simple physics based game.

But I'm struggling to create a `View` (LookAt) matrix. I'm trying to avoid adding any math library dependencies to project.

Could anyone share an example of how they create `View` matrix? So I could modify to work with my custom `Matrix4f` class.

Heres my method to setup orthographic projection matrix ..

```
public Matrix4f ortho(float left, float right, float top, float bottom, float zfar, float znear) {
    return new Matrix4f(new float[][] {
        new float[] { 2 / (right - left), 0, 0, -((right + left) / (right - left)) },
        new float[] { 0, 2 / (top - bottom), 0, -((top + bottom) / (top - bottom)) },
        new float[] { 0, 0, -2 / (zfar - znear), -((zfar + znear) / (zfar - znear)) },
        new float[] { 0, 0, 0, 1 },
    });
}
```

Heres my custom `Matrix4f` class ..

```
public class Matrix4f {

    public float[] values;

    public Matrix4f() {
        this.values = new float[16];
    }

    public Matrix4f(float[] values) {
        this.values = values;
    }

    public Matrix4f(float[][] values) {
        load(values);
    }

    public void load(float[][] values) {
        this.values = new float[] {
            values[0][0], values[0][1], values[0][2], values[0][3],
            values[1][0], values[1][1], values[1][2], values[1][3],
            values[2][0], values[2][1], values[2][2], values[2][3],
            values[3][0], values[3][1], values[3][2], values[3][3]
        };
    }

    public float get(int x, int y) {
        int position = x + (y * 4);
        return this.values[position];
    }

    public float[] getValues() { 
    return this.values; 
    }
}
```

Comment: Maybe [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/349050/calculating-a-lookat-matrix) can help.

Comment: If using opengl, be sure to use the positive dot product on the z translation, for the sake of compatibility.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

"Look at" matrix

```
f = normalize(target - position);
s = normalize(cross(f, up));
u = normalize(cross(s, f));

mat4 mat = mat4(1.0f);

mat.data[0] = s.x;
mat.data[4] = s.y;
mat.data[8] = s.z;

mat.data[1] = u.x;
mat.data[5] = u.y;
mat.data[9] = u.z;

mat.data[2] = -f.x;
mat.data[6] = -f.y;
mat.data[10] = -f.z;

mat.data[3] = 0.0f;
mat.data[7] = 0.0f;
mat.data[11] = 0.0f;

mat.data[12] = -dot(s, position);
mat.data[13] = -dot(u, position);
mat.data[14] = dot(f, position);
mat.data[15] = 1.0f;
```

Comment: just to confirm `(position, target, up)` are all 3-element vectors right? corresponding to what's passed to `glu.lookat`

Comment: yes, the w value is not needed for this calculation

Comment: OMG thank you, I've been fighting with this forever!